# Receive null values in spatial join with census tract data in QGIS

Tags: polygon, attribute-joins, census

I have tried this in both QGIS and GISmap. I am attempting to get average wind speed by census tract. I am using the census tract boundary information from ArcGIS Online (polygon ESRI data) as well as a raster file of average wind speed which I have converted to point data (nrel.gov data). When I attempt to spatially join the two files I get null values.

[image]

All I need is the FIPS data with the corresponding wind field value (VALUE), but they are not aligning to perform a spatial join.

Comment: I guess two questions for clarity: 1 - Are both layers in the same CRS? 2 - Your ArcGIS Online Layer, is it an ESRI Feature Service or a Web Mapping Service?